# Saving Json using core data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I am beginner in swift development. I am trying to save JSON received from a web service into my core data model. I achieve this by swiping left from the table view cell to save. The issues arises when I try to look at the saved data from a database, nothing shows. Also this error comes when the swipe feature activates   nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed. How do I resolve this ? Project link: https://github.com/lexypaul13/Covid-News

This code below handles persistence.

```
class CoreDataManger: NSObject {
    
    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataManger()
    private override init() {}
    
    var newsCoreData: [News] = []
    var article = ArticlesData()
 
    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    
    func createData(){
        
         DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { [self] in
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        
        //We need to create a context from this container
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        //Now let’s create an entity and new user records.
        let newsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "News", in: managedContext)!
        let news = NSManagedObject(entity: newsEntity, insertInto: managedContext)

        for article in self.newsCoreData{
         news.setValue("\(article.author ?? "")", forKeyPath: "author")
         news.setValue("\(article.myDescription ?? "")", forKeyPath: "myDescription")
         news.setValue("\(article.publishedAt ?? "")", forKeyPath: "publishedAt")
         news.setValue("\(article.title ?? "")", forKeyPath: "title")
         news.setValue("\(article.urlImage ?? "")", forKeyPath: "urlImage")
         news.setValue("\(article.urlWebsite ?? "")", forKeyPath: "urlWebsite")
 
        }
        
         
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            newsCoreData.append(news as! News)
            
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))

    }
        )}
}
```

This code swipes to save

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

let save =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Save") { (action, view, completionHandler) in
        completionHandler(true)
        
            CoreDataManger.sharedInstance.createData()
        
}
    save.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

    let swipe =  UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [save])
    return swipe
}
```

Comment: You need to create a new `News` object and do the `append` _inside_ the `for` loop. Right now you are only adding one object in the createData function

Comment: Hi, I am bit confused where should I place this object ?

Comment: `let news = NSManagedObject...`, this should be inside the `for` loop so you create a new object for each article